# How to redirect user after form submit in overlay mode?

Tags: 7, forms, modal-dialogs

The following code redirects user to `node/add/article` but doesn't use overlay.

`$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/article'`

How do I open `node/add/article` in overlay mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this,

```
global $base_url;
$custom_url =  (urldecode(url($base_url, array('query' => array('destination' => '#overlay=node/add/article')))));
$form_state['redirect'] = $custom_url;
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `The requested page "mysite.com/%23overlay%3Dnode/add/article" could not be found`

Comment: `urlencode()` ?

Comment: global $base_url;
$custom_url =  (urldecode(url($base_url, array('query' => array('destination' =>'#overlay=node/add/article')))));
$form_state['redirect'] = $custom_url;

now try this one

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the working solution:

Inside your form:

```
$form['somebutton']['#submit'] = array('your_custom_callback');
```

Add a custom callback

```
function your_custom_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  //redirect users to Drupal.org
  $url = "http://drupal.org";

  if (module_exists('overlay') && overlay_get_mode() == 'child') {
    unset($_GET['destination']);
    overlay_close_dialog($url, array('external' => TRUE));
    $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
  } else {
    $form_state['redirect'] = $url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code above didn't quite work for me - I had to include *$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;* within the overlay clause in the custom callback. The code below works for me:-

```
// the URL of the view I want to redirect to...
$redirect_to = 'manager/dashboard';

if(!empty($redirect_to)) {
    if (module_exists('overlay') && overlay_get_mode()=='child') {
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
        unset($_GET['destination']);
        overlay_close_dialog($redirect_to);
        $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        $form_state['redirect'] = $redirect_to;
    }
}
```